# Python string to binary string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, binary, converters

I need to convert a decimal read from a list in string form and output its binary equivalent to a text file.

I can convert the string to binary via:

```
line = format(int(strNUMBER), '016b')
```

but when I write it to a file it is in raw binary and not 16 ascii numbers as I want.

Is there a built in function flow to do this or will I need to walk the binary and fill a list with 1's and 0's manually?

Comment: Try: `"{0:b}".format(strNUMBER)`

Comment: You might be interested in the built-in `bin()` function.

Comment: @uMinded , do you mean you want to write to file as raw binary? or do you want to write to file as 16 ascii numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below method to get a 16 digit binary of an integer

```
a = '{0:016b}'.format(int(strNUMBER))
```

Comment: @uMinded your Welcome :)